# Measure distance driven on the run

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use google maps api to measure the distance that I actually drove with a car, therefore I won't set a location, the user just starts driving and the app uses the API to determine miles driven.

we should assume that the user will not follow the road that google maps gives once he sets a destination (using google maps directions).

Any solution is appreciated, even if it does not use google maps, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can suggest you;

- Create markers(or get locations without creating markers) in intervals
- Since you are driving, get as much as point you can to provide better data
- When you have your points, then you can create a polyline from these points
- Get length of your polyline(this will be the driven distance).

Then show the route and do whatever you want with the data you have :)

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) is a polyline example.

I am assuming you are going to use js, so [here](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp) is an example  how to get user's location.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

it uses [Bing's Routes API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx) or [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints), both returns a JSON response in which there is the distance travelled.

Both accepts coordinates (latitude and longitude) as way points to pass through will travelling.

each request using Bing's Routes API accepts a maximum of 250 coordinates.

each request using Google Maps Directions API accepts a maximum of 25 coordinates.

The logic I'm going use:

- My android application will collect coordinates each number of seconds.
- When I reach the limit of coordinates for a respective API I'm using or I finish my trip (press a button to signal to the application), the app creates the request url accordingly to the documentations then make a GET request to get the JSON after that retrieved the distance travelled.